# Higgs non-minimal coupling to gravity: Jordan and Einstein frame

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, higgs, modified-gravity

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.4624) paper they consider the Higgs non-minimally coupled to the Ricci scalar. I am trying to recalculate the steps from equation (5) until equation (10).

Let's start with (5):

$$\int d^4x\sqrt{-g} \left[f(h) R-\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu h\partial_\nu h -U(h)\right]$$

where $f(h)=(M_p^2+\xi h^2)/2$ and $U(h)=\frac{\lambda}{4}(h^2-v^2)^2$. They then proceed with the transformation of the metric:

$$g_{\mu\nu}\to \tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}\Omega^2,~~\tilde{g}^{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\nu}\Omega^{-2},.$$

If I plug this in I get:

$$\int d^4x\sqrt{-\tilde{g}\frac{1}{\Omega^8}} \left[f(h) R-\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu h\partial_\nu h -U(h)\right]$$
$$=\int d^4x\sqrt{-\tilde{g}} \left[\frac{f(h)}{\Omega^2} \frac{R}{\Omega^2}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\tilde{g}^{\mu\nu}}{\Omega^2}\partial_\mu h\partial_\nu h -\frac{1}{\Omega^4}U(h)\right]$$

From this they identify

$$\frac{f(h)}{\Omega^2}=\frac{1}{2}M_p^2\text{, i.e. }\Omega^2=1+\frac{\xi h^2}{M_p^2}.$$

This now looks almost as the end result in equation (10) of the paper that I cite at the beginning.

From the book of Sean Carroll (Appendix G) I get the relation for $n=4$ dimensions:

$$ \frac{R}{\Omega^2}=\tilde{R}+6\frac{g^{\alpha\beta}}{\Omega^3}\partial_\alpha\partial_\beta\Omega .$$

Evaluating the last piec gives me

$$\partial_\alpha\partial_\beta\Omega=\left[-\frac{1}{\Omega^3}\left(\frac{\xi h}{M_p^2}\right)+\frac{1}{\Omega}\frac{\xi}{M_p^2}\right]\partial_\alpha h\partial_\beta h+\frac{1}{\Omega}\frac{\xi h}{M_p^2}\partial_\alpha\partial_\beta h$$

This is almost what I want, but only almost. The term $\partial_\alpha\partial_\beta h$ is too much and also the second term in the square brackets is too much. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the second part of your question about the kinetic term, if we're starting with the kinetic term, call it $T$, with

$$ T = \frac{1}{2}g^{\mu \nu} (\partial_{\mu}h) (\partial_{\nu}h),  $$
then first notice that under the conformal transformation
$$g_{\mu \nu} \mapsto \tilde{g}_{\mu \nu} = \Omega^2 g_{\mu \nu},$$
the inverse metric transforms like
$$g^{\mu \nu} \mapsto \tilde{g}^{\mu \nu} = \Omega^{-2} g^{\mu \nu}$$
giving the desired
$$T = \frac{1}{2}\Omega^{2} \tilde{g}^{\mu \nu} (\partial_{\mu}h) (\partial_{\nu}h)$$
which when combined with the $\Omega^{-4}$ factor coming from the volume element gives the term listed in the paper. If you apply the transformation to both the coordinates and the metric like you have done in your example, the contributions cancel. As I understand it, in a conformal transformation like this you transform the metric but not the coordinates, which is where I believe your factors of $\frac{\partial \tilde{x}}{\partial x}$ are not in line with the paper's derivation.

The transformation of the Ricci tensor under conformal transformations is carried out in an appendix of Carroll's introduction to general relativity. I hope that reference is sufficient to answer your first question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! In the paper they also write things like $\tilde{\partial}_\mu$ which is I guess the derivative with respect to the new coordinate frame. This is the reason why I have the $\tilde{x}$. I imagine the conformal transformation as $\tilde{g}^{\alpha\beta}=\frac{\partial \tilde{x}^\alpha}{\partial x^\mu}\frac{\partial \tilde{x}^\beta}{\partial x^\nu}g_{\mu\nu}$. Then I can identify $\frac{\partial \tilde{x}^\alpha}{\partial x^\mu}=\delta^\alpha_\mu \Omega$. Then I can also introduce the Jacobi determinant, which I forgot to write down and which you already mentioned.

Comment: However when I do that I don't get the result in the paper. I am confused because for example in eq (8) they use the tilde for writing derivatives, but the $d^4x$  does not have tilde?

Comment: I think I also found out where the logarithms are coming from. [1] they write down the transformation of the form $e^{\Phi}$. Our transformation can be obtained by setting $\Phi=\log(\Omega^2)$!   [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Scalar_curvature_2

Comment: @jojo123456 No problem! I think there must be some difference in how we are understanding conformal transformations. It is my understanding that a conformal transformation acts solely on the metric, and is not an induced transformation of the metric by a change of coordinates. I believe the tildes over the derivatives in the paper to be referring to the fact that indices are raised and lowered by the transformed metric. Please correct me if you think I'm wrong about this, I am by no means an expert.

Comment: Ah okay! Yeah you are probably right. They could have written this in the text... I will do the calculation once more and then come back

Comment: Okay, I made a lot of progress. Thanks for your comments. Unfortunately I still do not get exactly the result which they quote in the paper. I updated the original post. Any ideas what could have gone wrong? In the end I used the relations from Sean Carrolls book and not the equations which contained the logarithm...

Comment: I think you may have used an expression from Carroll's book incorrectly. He has two lists of formulae in that appendix: the first take you from $R$ to $\tilde{R}$, and the second set take you back again. The derivation should come fairly immediately once you have taken the second expression, i.e. the one that writes $R$ in terms of $\tilde{R}$ and the transformed connection $\tilde{\nabla}_{\mu}$. In the edition I am looking at this is equation (G.16). Hope that helps.

Comment: To clarify: I believe your only mistake is in your equation relating $R$ and $\tilde{R}$.

Comment: You are right. I have to take the second relation since I want to express everything in the new frame. For everyone who has not the book: $R/ \Omega^2=\tilde{R}+6 \tilde{g}^{\alpha\beta}/\Omega(\tilde{\nabla}_\alpha\tilde{\nabla}_\beta\Omega)-12/\Omega^2\tilde{g}^{\alpha\beta}(\tilde{\nabla}_\alpha\Omega)(\tilde{\nabla}_\beta\Omega)$. I also found out that $\nabla$ is the covariant derivative in Carrolls notation.

Comment: My problem: How can I evaluate $g^{\alpha\beta}\tilde{\nabla}_\alpha\tilde{\nabla}_\beta\Omega$? I know that the covariant derivative of a general vactor field is $\tilde{\nabla}_\alpha V^\nu=\tilde{\partial}_\alpha V^\nu+\tilde{\Gamma}^{\nu}_{\alpha\sigma}V^\sigma$. Can I now simply write $g^{\alpha\beta}\tilde{\nabla}_\alpha\tilde{\nabla}_\beta\Omega=\tilde{\nabla}_\alpha\tilde{\nabla}^\alpha\Omega$ and apply the known relation? Or do I get extra terms if I pull the $g^{\alpha\beta}$ inside the covariant derivative?

Comment: For a metric $g$ compatible with a covariant derivative $\nabla$ you can move the metric through without worry. Here the only point to note is that $g$ is compatible with $\nabla$, and $\tilde{g}$ is compatible with $\tilde{\nabla}$. Since the two metrics are related as they are, this detail will only produce some factors of $\Omega$.